# Is there any way to compare between diagonals of a resolvent and a Cauchy transform?

Tags: pr.probability, fa.functional-analysis, sp.spectral-theory, random-matrices, convex-optimization

Say $A$ is a symmetric matrix of $n$ dimensions. Then let the ``resolvent" of $A$ be the matrix valued function $R_A(z) = \frac{1}{z-A}$ and its Cauchy transform be the real valued function $C_A(z) = Tr[R_A(z) ]$.

- I want to compare between the numbers $[R_A(z)]_{ii}$ and $\frac{1}{n} C_A(z)$.

  Do we know as to when is which of them larger and by how much?

  Like given a $A$ and a $i$ I want to understand when it will be true that, $[R_A(z)]_{ii} \leq \frac{1}{n} C_A(z)$ ?

---

If necessary assume that $z > \lambda_{max}(A)$

If necessary assume that $A$ is constructed as follows : First take the matrix $D - Ad$ where $D$ is the diagonal matrix of degrees of some bi-partite graph and $Ad$ is its adjacency matrix. Then flip some of the off-diagonal $-1$ entries of $D-A$ to $1$ keeping the entire thing symmetric.

Comment: Robert Israel's answer is the best possible: There is always some index $i$ which satisfies the inequality for trivial reasons. And no more can be said because the whole problem is invariant under base change, so we can reindex the rows and columns (i.e. conjugate $A$ by a permutation matrix) such that the index where the inequality holds is 1 or 42 or 4711 or any other index you want.

Comment: Since this question keeps getting bumped, would you consider accepting Robert Israel's answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trace is the sum of the diagonal elements, so (when $z$ is real) it's always true for at least one $i$, and the only way it can be true for all of them is that all diagonal elements are equal.   For example, this is the case for the matrix 
$$ A = \pmatrix{3 & 0 & 1 & -1\cr
                0 & 3 & 1 & -1\cr
                1 & 1 & 3 & 0\cr
                -1 & -1 & 0 & 3\cr} $$

Comment: Seems like I phrased the question badly! Sorry. I edited it. Say I fix an $i$ then I want to know as to when can the inequality be true.

Comment: I want to say something like this - that this inequality will always be true some $i$ for which the diagonal entry of $A$ is minimum. Something like this...

Comment: The A in your example doesn't satisfy the 3rd criteria of mine when I list the wanted properties of $A$.

Comment: You can add a constant multiple of the identity to make it satisfy that.  OK, I'll edit.

Comment: I am not getting you. Your example doesn't satisfy my 3rd crietria. And its not clear to me as to how it helps answer the question that I am asking.

Comment: Which third criteria?  That every diagonal element is the number of nonzero elements in that row/column?

Comment: Yes. You need to have "2" instead of "3" for a valid test-case.

Comment: So you mean the number of **off-diagonal** nonzero elements in the row/column.  OK, change the $3$'s to $2$'s.

Comment: Ah..ok..changed that. Any help with the question would be great. My gut feeling (from some experiments) is that for an A of this type the inequality is satisfied for $i$ such that $A_{ii}$ is minimum diagonal element of $A$. But I don't know how to go about this.